# Explain the equation

Tags: diodes, power-electronics

Explain the following equation...

$$
r^{\prime}_d = \dfrac{26\mathrm{mV}}{I_D} + r_B
$$

Explain from where and how this equation comes out . Also elaborate the terms used in above mentioned equation.

Comment: Explain the question

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: Can you give more context? The equation is like of the dinamic resistance for a polarized P-N junction... right?

Comment: Homework questions with no attempt at a solution are closed.

Comment: Sir,it;s not homework question.I just read it and don not understand that's why I asked.

Comment: Yes,it's an AC dynamic resistance.

Comment: Can anyone be kind enough to explain it for me?

Answer (score 2):

If it is the dynamic resistance of the diode, \$r_d\$ is the value of this resistance, when the diode is forward biased with a current \$I_D\$.

This starts from the analysis of the diode equation

$$
I = I_s\cdot \left(e^{\dfrac{q_e\,V}{\eta\,K\,T}} -1\right)
$$

and defining the dynamic resistance as

$$
r_d = \dfrac{dV}{dI}
$$

replacing \$K\$ for the Boltzmann's constant, \$T\$ the temperature, \$\eta\$ a coefficient between 1 y 2, \$q_e\$ the electron charge and \$I_s\$ the saturation current (minoritary carriers), an aproximate value is

$$
r_d \approx \dfrac{26\,\mathrm{mV}}{I}
$$

You can find a more detailed explanation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QF6V74D2hbY)